# What happened to Uhura, Chekov and Sulu?

Tags: star-trek

I know that TNG showed that Spock and McCoy were still alive, and it explained about Scotty, and Generations explained about Kirk, but does anyone know what happened to Sulu, Chekov or Uhura? I know that there was something mentioned somewhere in Voyager about a Captain Sulu having sponsored Chakotay's entrance into the academy, but if anyone else knows anything, I would be pleased to find out.

Comment: How canon do you want?  The reason I ask (and noting that this is now a duplicate) is [Star Trek: Renegades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Renegades) is of questionable canonicity though reprises many of the actors in their roles.

Comment: Just a thought, the Captain Sulu who sponsored Chakotay could have been Demora since, by then, she could easily have become a Captain and, I know this is non-canon, in the books she takes over from Harriman as captain of the Enterprise B